# Spring sql database connecting exception

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I just start learning spring. I was trying to fetch data from my data base using spring, but got exception from xml file. I dont know whats the issue, I searched alot but unable to fix it. Please help me out. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Main Class

```
package com.spring.demo;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        ApplicationContext cntxt = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        JdbcDaoImpl dao = cntxt.getBean("JdbcDaoImpl", JdbcDaoImpl.class);
        UserModel model = dao.getUserName("admin");


        model.display();
   }
}
```

DAO IMPLI

```
package com.spring.demo;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component
public class JdbcDaoImpl {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return dataSource;
    }

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    public UserModel getUserName(String userName){
        Connection con = null;

        try{
            con = dataSource.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from userinfo where userName = ?");
            ps.setString(1, "vaibhav");
            UserModel model = null;
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()){
                model = new UserModel();
                model.setUserName(rs.getString("userName"));
            }
            rs.close();
            ps.close(); 
            return model;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        finally{
            try{
                con.close();
            }
            catch(SQLException s){

            }
        }
    }



}
```

SPRING.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
   <context:annotation-config />
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.demo" />


   <bean id ="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
   <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" /> 
   <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testing" />
   <property name="userName" value="vaibhav" />
   <property name="password" value="bhopal@123" />
   </bean> 

</beans>
```

Console

```
Dec 05, 2015 12:10:16 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1c12fb0: startup date [Sat Dec 05 12:10:16 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Dec 05, 2015 12:10:16 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 20 in XML document from class path resource [spring.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 20; columnNumber: 69; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'property'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:509)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.spring.demo.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:12)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 20; columnNumber: 69; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'property'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: Which exception do you get ?

Comment: @Berger - sorry about that. I have updated with exception

Comment: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testing replace jdbc:mysql://localhost/testing if not working than tell which error is occur

Comment: @sanjay - this is what is get -- Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 37 in XML document from class path resource [spring.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 37; columnNumber: 95; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'bean'.

Answer (score 1):

Your xml namespace seems to be corrupted. As you are using beans through out the xml. Use beans as default namespace. Have corrected your spring.xml and validated it succesfully. So, the below xml snippet should work for you.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.demo" />


<bean id="dataSource"
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
   <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
   <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testing" />
   <property name="userName" value="vaibhav" />
   <property name="password" value="bhopal@123" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

You declared mvc and jdbc namespaces but didn't refer them with their respective xsd documents for validation. Let me know if the above piece of code doesn't work!

Comment: WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'userName' of bean class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource]: Bean property 'userName' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Did you mean 'username'?

Comment: So, you are done with xml validation errors. yeah try with username. Will see.

Comment: Its done...I correct it. Now there is another.can u plz clear this out as well where I am making mistakes. - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource cannot be cast to com.example.UserModel
 at com.example.Main.main(Main.java:12)

Comment: Hey buddy, it doesn't work this way. Paste the code of UserModel class here and the db table. I'll do it for you!

Comment: Have solved your question. Seems you missed few other things.

Comment: Have solved your question. Seems you missed few other things. I'm assuming you are trying to fetch username and password from db. In main method of MainApp class, you have to get the bean of 'jdbcDaoImpl' not the 'JdbcDaoImpl' class. This should fix the issue. As you are doing setter injection, add this statement in if(rs.next()) loop of JdbcDaoImpl.java class. 'model.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));' This will set the password member variable so that you can get and read the value from db. Let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: harshavmb - thanks for the help, I sorted out the above things but stuck somewhere else... I think maybe I am going to start irritating if I ask you another question.

Comment: Don't add further queries in comments under an individual answer, post each new problem as a new, well-defined question.

Answer (score 0):

Add the *util* namespace to your declarations :

```
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
```

And for the schemaLocation :

```
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd
```

Comment: After adding those I got this the same as I was getting - Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 37 in XML document from class path resource [spring.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 37; columnNumber: 95; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'bean'.

Answer (score 0):

Add this two line on **xsi:schemaLocation** in spring.xml file

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd

And I notice <beans:beans .....> so also change <bean id="..."> to <beans:bean id="..."> 

And also access property like this:
<beans:property>
```

Comment: Now there is another exception :  Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 28 in XML document from class path resource [spring.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 28; columnNumber: 69; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'property'.
 
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 28; columnNumber: 69; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'property'.

Comment: access property like this:
<beans:property> in spring.xml file